# Not able to specifically traverse through the syntax tree?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, roslyn, vsix

I'm trying to implement a Diagnostic Analyzer for Collection initializer and its corresponding Code Fix provider.

Wrong Code:

```
var sampleList= new List<string>();
sampleList.Add("");
sampleList.Add("");
```

After CodeFix:

```
var sampleList= new List<string>(){"", ""};
```

But I'm stuck at this problem that once I get a node for LocalDeclarationStatement, I'm not aware if there exists a way to get the very next adjacent node from the parent.

[image: Syntax Tree]

In the above Picture I require both the ExpressionStatement after analyzing the LocalDeclarationStatement

REQUIREMENT for analyzer

1. Identify the `LocalDeclarationStatement`, a collection that is already initialized but doesnt contain `CollectionInitializerExpression`
2. Find if the very next line has an Expression statement that is using `Add` method on the same collection

REQUIREMENT for Code fix

1. Provide Collection initializer syntax for the adjacent Expression statements that are using `Add` method on the collection
2. All other intermitten usage of Add method on the collection has to be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var declarationStatement = ...;
var block = (BlockSyntax)declarationStatement.Parent;
var index = block.Statements.IndexOf(declarationStatement);
var nextStatement = block.Statements[index + 1];
```

Comment: How do we remove the additional lines of code (the adjacent `Add` invocations) that were replaced with the Collection Initializer syntax using the same CodeFix provider. I was able to provide a fix  for collection initializer, but unable to remove the other consecutive lines of `Add` invocation.

Comment: @JerricLynsJohn Did you try the `RemoveNode` extension method?

Comment: @svick Yes I did, but it seems that didn't affect the the root. I'm not sure If I did it correctly. `root.RemoveNode(expression, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia)`

Comment: @JerricLynsJohn Just like everything in Roslyn, `RemoveNode` doesn't mutate the original tree, it returns a new one. So you need something like `root = root.RemoveNode(…);`.

Comment: @svick I've tried this, it is definitely working for removing a single node, but if I wanted to remove more and modify some, then I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure it out. [I've posted this as another question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505020/how-to-remove-a-list-of-syntaxnode-from-the-document-using-roslyn-code-fix-provi).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just need to turn the concrete block into list, and check?

```
var nodes = yourSyntaxTree.DescentNodes().ToList();

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++){
  var localDeclarationStatement = nodes[i] as LocalDeclarationStatement;
  if(localDeclarationStatement==null && i + 1 >= nodes.Length)
      continue;

  var expressionStatement = nodes[i+1] as ExpressionStatement;
  if(expressionStatement==null)
     continue;

  // there you have it.
}
```