# How to remove a list of SyntaxNode from the Document using Roslyn code fix provider APIs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, roslyn, vsix

I'm having a custom generated variable declaration using `SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration` and a list of `SyntaxNode`'s collected according to some conditions.

I did the following:

1. **Modify the node**

   ```
   var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(expression, newVariableDeclaration)
   ```

   This successfully modified the node with the `newVariableDeclaration`.
2. **In a loop remove the nodes corresponding to the ones present in the list**

   ```
   foreach (var listObject in listObjects)
   {
       newRoot = newRoot.RemoveNode(listObject, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
   }
   ```

   This doesn't change the `newRoot` and all the `listObject` required to be changed remains the same.

*If we use `root.RemoveNode(listObject, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia)` instead it will, obviously, keep on replacing the previous changes.*

So here the `newVariableDeclaration` is the **only node that is changed** in the whole document, is this because `newRoot` `SyntaxNodes` have changes from that of the `SyntaxNode` that I obtained from `root`.

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

**EDIT:**
I looked into `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` but it appears that it is analyzing a single node everytime it's visiting a node and can only modify a single node at a time. In my scenario, I'll have to visit a particular node, make changes to it, and remove other nodes with respect to the changes made to visited node.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your approach is that whenever you change the tree (using `ReplaceNode()` or `RemoveNode()`), it means all the nodes change as well. This is why your calls to `RemoveNode()` after `ReplaceNode()` don't do anything.

One way to fix this is to use `TrackNodes()`, so that you can find which nodes in the modified tree correspond to nodes in the original tree.

Uisng this, a method that replaces a sequence of nodes with a single node could look like this:

```
public static T ReplaceNodes<T>(
    this T root, IReadOnlyList<SyntaxNode> oldNodes, SyntaxNode newNode)
    where T : SyntaxNode
{
    if (oldNodes.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    var newRoot = root.TrackNodes(oldNodes);

    var first = newRoot.GetCurrentNode(oldNodes[0]);

    newRoot = newRoot.ReplaceNode(first, newNode);

    var toRemove = oldNodes.Skip(1).Select(newRoot.GetCurrentNode);

    newRoot = newRoot.RemoveNodes(toRemove, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);

    return newRoot;
}
```

Comment: This answer works, and is still very relevant with the current API on .NET 6